# .NET - Error message when .NET is not installed

Tags: .net, error-handling

I have a .NET 2.0 application, which could run many OSs - Windows XP, 7, Server 2003, Server 2008, Server 2008 R2 (Full and Core), Server 2012 (Full and Core).

I have added a `.exe.config` file for the application which lists the supported runtimes (2.0.50727 and 4.0).

Now, when this is run on any machine except a Server Core machine which does not have .NET installed, an error message is displayed saying that the user needs to install one of the listed .NET versions (2.0.50727 and 4.0).

However, for 2008 R2 Server Core, the message says

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000135)

(followed by one more line).

For Server 2012 Core, nothing is displayed at all and the command line just moves to the next line.

Why is there a difference is these error messages? Is there any way to have the same message as for the non-Core machines?

Comment: Handle them in which sense? By your application? No. From a batch file? From a calling process?

Comment: I just want the same message as for the non-Core machines. I believe the message for the non-Core is displayed because it could not find one of the .NET versions listed in the .exe.config file. Why doesnt the same happen for the Core machines ?